# What can I do to get my docking station to connect to my desktop over USB-C?

Tags: usb, compatibility, computer-building, docking-station

### Goal / Problem

I am looking to connect a new docking station to my home desktop. Unfortunately, when I connect my dock's cable to the USB-C port on my desktop, nothing appears on the screen connected to the dock and the dock indicator light says there is no connection.

#### My Setup:

**Desktop**

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home

Baseboard: Gigabyte Z390 UD

BIOS Version: F10

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 (USB-C VirtualLink port)

**Docking Station**

Dell Universal Dock UD22 (USB 3.2 Gen2 Type-C cable)

### Possible Solutions

- Continue to troubleshoot and identify the source of the problem
- Add an additional USB-C port: I have an open PCI-e slot on my desktop that I could add an additional card to, if this is likely a hardware problem

### Troubleshooting:

So far, I've taken the following steps to try and troubleshoot the problem and have contacted technical support from both Dell and NVIDIA with no luck so far.

1. Installed the Dell DisplayLink Dock Driver on my Desktop

2. Updated the firmware on the docking station using the Dell Universal Dock UD22 Firmware Update Utility

3. Updated my NVIDIA Drivers

4. Updated my BIOS Drivers

5. Validated that the USB-C slot on the GPU does function by connecting it to a monitor with a USB-C to HDMI adapter

6. Validated that the Docking Station connects to both a Dell Precision5560 Laptop running Windows 10 Pro and a 2020 MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura

7. Confirmed that the connection indicator light on the dock is functioning properly by determining that the dock does not appear in the Device Manager when I place the dock's cable in the NVIDIA USB-C Port (the dock appears as a Universal Serial Bus device in the Device manager when connecting to the Dell Laptop)

If anyone can offer any advice, it would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information

Comment: It doesn’t appear your GPU supports the dock you purchased since it doesn’t support USB Type-C DisplayPort mode. Most desktop GPUs have no reason to support it.

Comment: And in any case this dock is just a DisplayLink device. Nothing to do with "BIOS" or Nvidia drivers. It needs DisplayLink drivers (provided by Dell or directly from the chipset manufacturer) and be connected to a normal USB-C port. That's all.

Comment: And please don't post duplicates: [How can I connect my Desktop to my Docking Station?](https://superuser.com/questions/1794334/how-can-i-connect-my-desktop-to-my-docking-station)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for the correction, I completed additional troubleshooting on my problem and updated the question, so I assumed I should create a new question with that information included. I will not do that in the future


As to your advice, the desktop has DisplayLink Drivers installed and the port being used is a USB-C port.

Comment: @DanielB I'm not concerned with graphics performance on this device at the moment. But I appreciate you clarifying

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, that answers my question then. Can you recommend any expansion cards that support DisplayPort mode?

Comment: @DerekTank - Your GPU should already support it.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm a bit confused. Are you saying the RTX 2070 or the UD 22 doesn't support Display Port mode? Because unless I'm totally off base, the dock definitely supports USB Type-C DisplayPort Mode. In fact, it requires it according to the user guide, "ensure that your computer has a USB Type-C with DisplayPort Alt Mode". Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @DerekTank - GPU doesn’t support it. Desktop GPUs have no reason to support Type-C Alt Mode since they typically have support both HDMI and DisplayPort natively. What you probably wanted was a DisplayPort KVM.